# Syntax error on While loop in python

Tags: python, syntax, while-loop

I get a syntax error at the first while loop, specifically at the "Y"

```
#Calculates trajectory under various angles
from math import*
from Density import*
from Fdrag import*
from pylab import title, xlabel, ylabel, show, plot, legend

#constants
rho0=1.2            #standard density of air at ground (kg/m^3)
g=9.81              #acceleration due to gravity (m/s/s)
T0=288.15           #ground temperature
D=0.1               #diameter (m)
A=pi*D^2/4          #Area
m=4                 #mass (kg)

for theta in (25, 50, 75):  #range of trajectories
    #initial conditions
    V=2800                  #velocity m/s
    Vx=V*cos(theta)         #horizontal velocity component
    Vy=V*sin(theta)         #vertical velocity component
    t=0                     #time
    dt=0.01                #time step (s)
    X=0                     #position
    Y=0.0                     #position
    x=[0]                    #position list (x component)
    y=[0]                    #position list (y component)
    vx=[Vx]                   #velocity list (x component)
    vy=[Vy]                   #velocity list (y component)
    T=[]                    #time list
    peaked=0                #use peakes as flag

    While Y>=0:
Then the rest of my code
```

Answer (score 2):

`While` has to be written with a lowercase 'w', otherwise Python wont recognize it/

Comment: whoops, looks like I got beat to it by seconds.

Comment: @chown it would have been longer, except for the stupid 30 character limit

Answer (score 1):

While should be lowercase (`while`)

Answer (score 0):

`While` should be `while` (lower case 'w') in the `While Y>=0:` line at the end of the script.

Comment: @hodofhod same here, by 7 seconds =)

Comment: it would have been more like 20 seconds earlier, except for the stupid 30 character limit